# Translate Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

i have translated a plugin in german.

membership 1.x

i took the language.pot file and translate all lines.

after that a changed the Information:
[image]

i have uploaded the file to server and replaced the old one... but it stil in english... blog is in german "de_DE"

can someone help me?!

Comment: How do you have named the uploaded file? de_DE.mo? The name must be the same of the language of your blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't translate the `.pot` file (it's the source of all translations), you should instead copy it and name it after the textdomain specified inside the plugin (assuming it's written to support translation). If there are other translations already made, look at the name of those files, otherwise look for a line like this in the plugin:

```
load_plugin_textdomain('name', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)));
```

here `name` is what you should call your file, followed by the locale specification i.e.:

```
name-de_DE.po
```

then you have to compile the `.po` file into `.mo` (there are [several ways](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology) to do it depending on your operating system) and upload it in the correct directory.

Comment: i created a membership.po and membership.mo file i have add this line to main plugin file: load_plugin_textdomain('membership', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__))."/membershipincludes/languages/"); but still doenst working :(

Comment: You have to add the locale to the filename: textdomain + dash + locale. Ex: `membership-de_DE.po`